# Stuck or hanging issue when deploying a NextJs app to firebase hosting

Tags: next.js, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting, firebase-tools

I have a NextJS app that I am trying to deploy to firebase hosting, however during the `firebase deploy` command it seems to get stuck and hang indefinitely (several hours waiting to no avail). The deployment log is below

This is the `next.config.js`:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  experimental: { appDir: true },
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

My node version is `v16.8.0` and my NPM version is `7.21.0`

When initializing firebase, I ran `firebase experiments:enable webframeworks` and then `firebase init` to initialize the project, after that I ran `firebase deploy` and this is the log:

```
Detected a Next.js codebase. This is an experimental integration, proceed with caution.

warn  - You have enabled experimental feature (appDir) in next.config.js.
warn  - Experimental features are not covered by semver, and may cause unexpected or broken application behavior. Use at your own risk.
info  - Thank you for testing `appDir` please leave your feedback at https://nextjs.link/app-feedback

info  - Creating an optimized production build
info  - Compiled successfully
info  - Linting and checking validity of types
info  - Collecting page data
[    ] info  - Generating static pages (0/7)styles.container Header_container__mD0ij
info  - Generating static pages (7/7)
info  - Finalizing page optimization

Route (pages)                              Size     First Load JS
┌ ○ / (617 ms)                             3.71 kB         109 kB
├   └ css/fdb2f6acb69fe1ad.css             794 B
├   /_app                                  0 B            97.3 kB
├ ○ /404                                   179 B          97.5 kB
├ ○ /biography (461 ms)                    3.48 kB         111 kB
├   └ css/65eda0ce9bb2b5b9.css             1.45 kB
├ ○ /indexx (405 ms)                       4.56 kB         112 kB
├   └ css/2805e6d097bc0e08.css             2.95 kB
├ ○ /news (399 ms)                         2.69 kB         110 kB
├   └ css/e3f7d4147fa456f7.css             1.1 kB
└ ○ /shop (623 ms)                         1.62 kB         107 kB
    └ css/75bc53145ed6cfe5.css             506 B
+ First Load JS shared by all              127 kB
  ├ chunks/main-d2e0a2e45955cc22.js        78.7 kB
  ├ chunks/pages/_app-e1b5cdce79d3f8aa.js  17 kB
  ├ chunks/webpack-e5138252bb357a88.js     1.6 kB
  └ css/b57b70b80e694460.css               29.3 kB

○  (Static)  automatically rendered as static HTML (uses no initial props)

Building a Cloud Function to run this application. This is needed due to:
 • Image Optimization
 • app directory (unstable)
 • non-static route /biography
 • non-static route /news
 • non-static route /indexx
 • and 1 other reasons, use --debug to see more

Unable to bundle next.config.js for use in Cloud Functions, proceeding with deploy but problems may be enountered.
The command line is too long.


changed 1 package in 49s

119 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

=== Deploying to 'moudstest-proj'...

i  deploying functions, hosting
i  functions: preparing codebase firebase-frameworks-moudstest-proj for deployment
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  artifactregistry: ensuring required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled...
+  artifactregistry: required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled
+  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
+  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
!  functions: package.json indicates an outdated version of firebase-functions. Please upgrade using npm install --save firebase-functions@latest in your functions directory.
!  functions: Please note that there will be breaking changes when you upgrade.
i  functions: Loaded environment variables from .env.
i  functions: preparing .firebase\moudstest-proj\functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged D:\Projects\MENA\MZPersonalWebsite\.firebase\moudstest-proj\functions (127.64 MB) for uploading
i  functions: ensuring required API run.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API eventarc.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API pubsub.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API storage.googleapis.com is enabled...
+  functions: required API eventarc.googleapis.com is enabled
+  functions: required API run.googleapis.com is enabled
+  functions: required API storage.googleapis.com is enabled
+  functions: required API pubsub.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: generating the service identity for pubsub.googleapis.com...
i  functions: generating the service identity for eventarc.googleapis.com...
```

**What I can see from the log:**

1. The deployment is hanging at `functions: generating the service identity for eventarc.googleapis.com` even though the internet connection is stable and there are no clear errors.
2. Half way through the deployment it prints out `Unable to bundle next.config.js for use in Cloud Functions, proceeding with deploy but problems may be enountered.` `The command line is too long.` I'm not sure what the cause is.

Comment: I'm also facing similar issue with hosting nextjs on firebase. But mine stuck at:  " Building a Cloud Function to run this application. This is needed due to:
 • non-static route /admin
 • non-static route /admin/login
 • non-static route /api/hello "

Comment: @RuD3B0y I am having the same issue. Were you able to resolve it?

Comment: @RuD3B0y Deployment worked for me after downgrading firebase-tools to v11.19.0 `npm install -g firebase-tools@v11.19.0` 
Created an issue here: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/5622

Comment: @hkropp I tried to conact firebase support team. They recommened to use firebase tools v11.18.0.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still having that issue. Try changing the rewrite config in `firebase.json` to something like the below:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "source": ".",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/nextjsFunc",
        "function": "ssrYOUR_PROJECT_NAME"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Explanation: nextJS uses Server Side Rendering (SSR) and deploys a function to Firebase. With the migration to Function v2 some things have changed on the Firebase side on how that function gets deployed/named.